# Change "from" field in LotusNotes

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm sending an email using LotusNotes API, what I need to do is to change the "from" field value, please find the code below:

```
public void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String bodyText,String from) throws NotesException {

    Session dominoSession = NotesFactory.createSession(dominoServer, dominoUsername, dominoPassword);
    Database dominoDb = dominoSession.getDatabase(dominoServer, dominoMailbox);

    Document memo = dominoDb.createDocument();
    memo.appendItemValue("Form", "Memo");
    memo.appendItemValue("Importance", "1");
    memo.appendItemValue("Subject", subject);
    memo.appendItemValue("Body", bodyText);
    memo.send(false, recipient);

    dominoDb.recycle();
    dominoSession.recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it, to set the "from" property:

```
public void sendEmail(final String recipient, final String subject, final String bodyText, final String from) throws NotesException {

    final Session dominoSession = NotesFactory.createSession(dominoServer, dominoUsername, dominoPassword);
    final Database dominoDb = dominoSession.getDatabase(dominoServer, dominoMailbox);

    final Document mail = dominoDb.createDocument();
    mail.appendItemValue("Form", "Memo");
    mail.appendItemValue("Importance", "1");
    mail.appendItemValue("Subject", subject);
    mail.appendItemValue("Body", bodyText);
    mail.replaceItemValue("From", from + "@NotesDomain");
    mail.replaceItemValue("InetFrom", from);
    mail.send(false, recipient);

    dominoDb.recycle();
    dominoSession.recycle();
}
```

Comment: You are inserting the mail into mail.box there. I think you may have to add SMTPOriginator as well.

Comment: I don't know, but this is how it worked with me, I didn't even know that I'm inserting in mail.box for me I'm just setting 2 properties.

Comment: I didn't need to set SMTPOriginator.

I tried to set the properties using your post, but it didn't work with me as also I'm not aware of the lotus script.

can you please tell me what is the mail.box, and how did I insert it in the mail.box by setting those 2 properties?

Answer (score 4):

You can't change it. The server always puts the current username into the 'From' field. You can have a different sender in the 'Principal', but the mail will still show who actually sent it.
But there is a workaround: instead of sending the mail put the mail document directly into mail.box on the server. Then you can use the 'From' field content of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm a beginner in LotusNotes API, you mean to add a line like this: memo.replaceItemValue("Principal/From", from); to set the from field but I don't understand how to save the document into mail.box?

Comment: It really would be best, as a beginner, to simply set the value of Principal, rather than monkeying with the mail.box. Use memo.replaceItemValue("Principal", from)

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work with me, and I posted an answer with the way it worked with me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I edited Michele's answer to clarify things a little bit. If you are a beginner, I would not suggest that you use the (undocumented) mail.box approach... You need to know what you are doing there.

I created a mail notification class in Lotusscript a while back, you can take a look at it if you like. Perhaps it will help you.

http://blog.texasswede.com/lotusscript-mail-notification-class/

But again, if you don't know what you are doing, be very very careful... :-)